# How to send an email between the desktop application(outlook express)and the blackberry ESS(email server simulator) in connected mode

Tags: sendmail, blackberry-simulator, outlook

i had succesfully sending an mail from ESS to the outlook express in standalone mode .but,now i want to send an mail by the connected mode in ESS.
can anybody know ,how to done it.

Comment: The ESS tag is already in use for Emacs Speaks Statistics. Maybe blackberry-ess would be an appropriate alternative?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i found the answer by myself.sending an mail through ESS in connected mode is not too big to do.

**ESS**
just start the ESS ,in which type the name of smtp and pop3 .then type the email address and password in it and then click launch

**outlook express**
go to the accounts to create as follows 
tools->Accounts.
the dialog box appears with tabs.in that check the security,connection and the advanced tabs .

in security tab,check for the smtp and the pop3 server name.

in connection tab ,make an available connection.

in advanced tab ,check for the port numbers for smtp and pop3 servers.
then click ok .
atlast sending of an email gives an successful result.

**Note**
1.use the free email relay servers.
2.use the account in the free email servers.
3.in the security tab,click to enable the checkbox of login secure password authentication and the my outgong mail server.

Comment: i found relar email server information in microsoft outlook helpsite and found enable check box in the server error with port 110 and 25